# Suppressing exceptions when using Cloudrail to logout of Box

Tags: android, cloudrail

In my app I use "service.logout" in Cloudrail to log out of Box. If it is already logged out an exception is thrown. I can ignore this exception in my app but is it possible to suppress it completely? Note that no exception is thrown in the equivalent circumstances in Cloudrail using `OneDrive` or `DropBox`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: ServiceCode Error in function
>   Authenticating:logout at 3  at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:108)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.callFunction(Interpreter.java:42)
>                                                                                                      at com.cloudrail.si.services.Box.logout(Box.java:1328)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.dpw.photoplayer.Activity_Connections$LoginToCloudRailDrive.onRun(Activity_Connections.java:705)
>                                                                                                      at com.birbit.android.jobqueue.Job.safeRun(Job.java:229)
>                                                                                                      at com.birbit.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.safeRun(JobHolder.java:132)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.handleRunJob(ConsumerManager.java:398)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.access$000(ConsumerManager.java:317)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer$2.handleMessage(ConsumerManager.java:345)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.messaging.SafeMessageQueue.consume(SafeMessageQueue.java:36)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.run(ConsumerManager.java:380)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.commands.string.Concat.execute(Concat.java:41)
>                                                                                                      at com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:84)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.cloudrail.si.servicecode.Interpreter.callFunction(Interpreter.java:42) 
>                                                                                                      at com.cloudrail.si.services.Box.logout(Box.java:1328) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.dpw.photoplayer.Activity_Connections$LoginToCloudRailDrive.onRun(Activity_Connections.java:705) 
>                                                                                                      at com.birbit.android.jobqueue.Job.safeRun(Job.java:229) 
>                                                                                                      at com.birbit.android.jobqueue.JobHolder.safeRun(JobHolder.java:132) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.handleRunJob(ConsumerManager.java:398) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.access$000(ConsumerManager.java:317) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer$2.handleMessage(ConsumerManager.java:345) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.messaging.SafeMessageQueue.consume(SafeMessageQueue.java:36) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.birbit.android.jobqueue.ConsumerManager$Consumer.run(ConsumerManager.java:380) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually unintended behavior, there shouldn't be an error. We fixed that together with our new version of the SDK (v2.7.0). Let me know if this solved the issue. With the new version we also released our first version of the new developer portal which allows you to get statistics about your app(s) and stay informed about any SDK updates or critical bug fixes. You can create a free account at developers.cloudrail.com.

Comment: I confirm that v2.7.0 cures this issue. Fyi, I have also implemented the new portal.